# Writing the most basic Unit test in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, ecmascript-6, angular

**Problem:** As soon as I import [Angular 2](https://angular.io/) into a file none of my tests execute.

**Question:** How can I set up my [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) config to support angular two so my test pass properly?

**OR**
**Question:** How can I set up any testing framework with angular2 written in es6?

[Git Repo (make sure you're on branch **angular-2**](https://github.com/matthewharwood/Hit-the-gym/tree/angular-2)

**Karma:**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jun 01 2015 14:16:41 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    jspm: {
        loadFiles: [
            'client/app/**/*.js'
        ]
    },

    // list of files to exclude

    plugins:[
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-jspm',
            'karma-chrome-launcher'
        ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

**JS:**

```
"use strict";
import {ComponentAnnotation as Component, ViewAnnotation as View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import List from './list/list';

//@Component({selector: 'my-app'})
//@View({template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`})
class Todo{
    constructor(){
        this.title = 'Gym';
        this.list = [new List()];
    }

    setTitle(newTitle){
        this.title = newTitle;
    }

    addListItem(){
        this.list.push(new List());
    }

    removeListItem(){
        this.list.pop();
    }
}
export default Todo;
```

**Todo.spec.js:**

```
import Todo from './todo';
describe('Todo list:', function(){
    var todo;
    beforeEach(function(){
        todo = new Todo();
    });

    it('expect Todo to be present', function(){
        expect(todo).not.toBe(null);
    });

    it('expect Todo constructor to accept a title', function(){
         expect(todo.title).toEqual('Gym');
    });

    it('expect Todo List property to be Present', function(){
        expect(todo.list).not.toBe(null);
    })

    it('expect Todo List property to accept a title:empty', function(){

         expect(todo.list[0].title).toEqual('empty');
    });

    it('expect Todo Title property to accept a title change', function(){
         todo.setTitle('Work');
         expect(todo.title).toEqual('Work');
    });

    it('expect Todo List property to have an add function', function(){
         todo.addListItem();
         expect(todo.list.length).toEqual(2);
    });

    it('expect Todo to have a remove function', function(){
         todo.removeListItem();
         expect(todo.list.length).toEqual(0);
    })
});
```

**Expected errors:**

```
$ karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.36 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [web-server]: 404: /favicon.ico
INFO [Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3)]: Connected on socket 31YT5XsHM29BDG8sYXSq with id 13157663
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.002 secs / 0 secs)
```

**If I remove angular import for Todo.js**

```
$ karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.36 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [web-server]: 404: /favicon.ico
INFO [Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3)]: Connected on socket 7QKCB-7aTRwNsOGfYjmG with id 71239348
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 7 of 7 SUCCESS (0.008 secs / 0.005 secs)
```

**UPDATE FROM GITTER:**

> @matthewharwood try loading the bundled ng2 file into your jspm Loadfiles section. with the karma-jspm plugin you can specify custom paths, so you can override the angular/angular path to point to that single bundled file. it made our tests run a lot easier. also I had to include the karma babel preprocessor and run my code thru that.

Unfortunatly I'm unable to get loadfiles working properly :c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After opening the debug page you could see that angular was telling you that it was missing the `reflect-metadata` package. So I added a manual import statement, for it in `app/todo/todo.js` which solved the issue:

```
import Reflect from 'reflect-metadata'
import { ComponentAnnotation as Component, ViewAnnotation as View } from 'angular2/angular2';
import List from './list/list';
```

My output is now:

```
node_modules/.bin/karma start --single-run
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.36 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [web-server]: 404: /favicon.ico
INFO [Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3)]: Connected on socket cGnqva8p5bf-j7L2EVzI with id 94803307
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 7 of 7 SUCCESS (0.005 secs / 0.004 secs)
```